# Как убрать пробелы в списке

Tags: python, list

У меня есть список

```py
word = ['    ', 'hello', '  ']
```

Как удалить пустые строки из списка?

Делаю на пайтоне

Comment: ваша постановка задачи немного вводит в заблуждение. Яимею ввиду следующее: по определению в пайтоне пустая строка это '', а это - ' ' -- строка пробелов из одного пробелов )

Comment: Знаете ли вы, что `'\f\x85\x1c\x1d\r\v\u2028\u2029'.strip()` даст пустую строку?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте функцию `strip` для каждого из элементов.

```py
word = [' ', 'hello', ' ']
word = [w for w in word if w.strip()]
print(word)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Можно еще использовать `str.isspace()`

Comment: если этот код оставить как есть, то строки вида `'\n'`  тоже будут отброшены. является ли такая строка "пустой" по требованию задачи это увы неясно.  Поэтому предложенное решение выглядит неполным )

Comment: @VasylKolomiets думаю, имелись ввиду значения, которые не содержат полезной нагрузки в виде символов.

Comment: \x00 - символ NULL
\x01 - символ START OF HEADING
\x02 - символ START OF TEXT
\x03 - символ END OF TEXT
\x04 - символ END OF TRANSMISSION
\x05 - символ ENQUIRY
\x06 - символ ACKNOWLEDGE
\x07 - символ BELL
\x08 - символ BACKSPACE
\t - символ HORIZONTAL TAB
\n - символ LINE FEED
\x0b - символ VERTICAL TAB

Comment: \f - символ FORM FEED
\r - символ CARRIAGE RETURN
\x0e - символ SHIFT OUT
\x0f - символ SHIFT IN
\x10 - символ DATA LINK ESCAPE
\x11 - символ DEVICE CONTROL ONE
\x12 - символ DEVICE CONTROL TWO
\x13 - символ DEVICE CONTROL THREE
\x14 - символ DEVICE CONTROL FOUR
\x15 - символ NEGATIVE ACKNOWLEDGE
\x16 - символ SYNCHRONOUS IDLE
\x17 - символ END OF TRANSMISSION BLOCK
\x18 - символ CANCEL
\x19 - символ END OF MEDIUM
\x1a - символ SUBSTITUTE
\x1b - символ ESCAPE
\x1c - символ FILE SEPARATOR

Comment: мне сложно выбрать, какие из них несут полезную нагрузку, а какие - нет )))
ну это третья задача вообще

Comment: `'\f\x85\x1c\x1d\r\v\u2028\u2029'.strip()`   даст пустую строку

Answer (score 2):

Пайтон позволяет писать почти по английски.
Вам надо отфильтровать пустые строки? Так и пишем - `filter()`:

```
words = [' ', 'hello', ' ']
filtered_words = list(filter(None, words))
print(filtered_words)
```

Ну использовать `list()` нужно если вам нужен новый список,  а если просто дальше обрабатывать в цикле поэлементно, то можно оставить в виде генератора `filter(None, words)`.

*В то же время по определению в пайтоне пустая строка это '', а это - ' ' -- строка пробелов из одного пробелов )*
Работу кода первого ответа можно повторить так:

```
words = [' ', 'hello', ' ']
filtered_words = list(filter(str.strip, words))
print(filtered_words)
```

Если же действительно надо убрать строки состоящие *из пробелов* (а не из спецсимволов в т.ч.) то пишем так:

```
words = [' ', 'hello', '\n']
filtered_words = list(filter(lambda x : x.strip(' '), words))
print(filtered_words)
```

Выдаст нам

```
['hello', '\n']
```

Если есть желание  -  проверьте какой из ответов работает быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Генератор (`(...)`) отбирает не пробельные строки (`if not w.isspace()`) и записывает их в старый список (`[:] =`):

```
word = [' ', 'hello', ' ']

#                       генератор
#         ------------------------------------
word[:] = (w for w in word if not w.isspace())
#   -----                  ------------------
#   правим                     если строка
#   список                    не пробельная
#  на месте

print(word)
```

**P.S.** Строки в примере не пустые а пробельные. Пустая строка - строка в которой нет символов совсем. В пробельной строке - все символы пробельные - пробел, табуляция, перевод строки и т.п.

Comment: доброта спасет человечество )